# Application works in emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I had just started developing an application for android. The application works seamlessly on emulator. But, when it comes to real devices, it only works till ics but throws an error at the end of the application exit on jelly bean and kit Kat devices . Moreover, if I emulate the same application on my emulator with jelly bean as my os version then I have no errors or exceptions thrown( the app seams to work perfectly well) . Why is this happening ? Also, my ask minimum target is set to api level 8 and max sdk target to api level : 21 in my manifest.xml. Could anyone possibly give any solutions for this ? Would appreciate that! Thanks to all those talented developers in advance.

The error goes like this on the real device : your application stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: What is the error in logcat?

Comment: I have no error thrown in logcat in my emulator bro! That's the saddest part. I only have error on real devices that too only post ics device

Comment: If your device is connected via USB it should show an error in logcat.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one ics device at home. I was checking on my friends device . Is there a way to get the logcat without connecting it to eclipse? Are there any application to do this without connecting the device through usb ?

Comment: You could use [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd)

Comment: Yeah tried that but not able to get the report. It doesn't give me a proper error report.

Comment: Can you change your app target version to API 19 and check ? As we've issues with 20 or so ?